# can count(*) return a different result from just count

Tags: sql, count

for example can this query

```
select count(*) from table
```

return something different than this query:

```
select count(column) from table
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `COUNT(*)` counts all rows
- `COUNT(column)` counts non-NULLs only

Comment: You forget `count( distinct column )` ;)

Comment: danihp: Not for the scope of this question.